# Name for phrase of words in increasing significance

Tags: phrases, rhetoric, figures-of-speech, terminology

I'm looking at the phrase "THE GOOD, THE BAD, AND THE UGLY". The thing I'm trying to think of is the joke format where you list a bunch of things and then change the last word for humorous effect. I believe that this phrase fits the same format, as "ugly" can be replaced with something absurd. The reason I need the name for this is so I can articulate the significance of the phrase in an infographic.

Comment: It's usually known as a setup, or a straight line. This has a "1, 2, 3*" structure, with the asterisk on "3" indicating a change-of-pace (an American idiom for a slow ball in baseball, btw, often pronunced "change-up").

Comment: As in [There are three kinds of lies: lies, damned lies, and **statistics**.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lies,_damned_lies,_and_statistics)

Comment: I recall "Love, life, and Fruit of the Loom".

Comment: Rather disappointingly, TV Tropes just calls this ["The Triple"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheTriple).

Comment: @jwodder Yeah, that's what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In rhetoric, this *omne trium perfectum* (all in threes is perfect or rule of three) is referred to as ***crescendo***, ***auxesis*** or ***climax*** - an arrangement in order of increasing importance.

[***Auxesis***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxesis_(figure_of_speech)) also refers more generally to placement of words or phrases in certain order to obtain climactic effect.

When restricted to three phrases it can be referred to as ***tricolon***. *Tricolons* can have ***crescendo*** and ***decrescendo*** variants.

This manner of speech is also sometimes referred to as ***hendiatris.***

[***hendiatris***](http://rowlandrhetoric.wikispaces.com/Hendiatris) (Greek for *one through three*)

Examples:

*sex, drugs, rock n roll.*

*Friends, Romans, Countrymen*

*Wine, women and song*

*life, liberty, and pursuit of happiness*

Answer (score 4):

The three elements of the phrase “the good, the bad, and the ugly” are an instance of what is called the “rule of three”, a literary device which engages the hearer using a pattern that is easy to commit to memory. The significance of three seems to be that the hearer cannot be expected to see a pattern in fewer things. You will find the rule of three used heavily in any kind of storytelling.

[Christopher Booker points out](http://books.google.com/books?id=qHJj9gOl0j8C) that there are four basic variations on the rule of three: simple, progressive, contrasting, and dialectical.

Using Booker’s organizing principle, it’s not quite clear how to categorize “the good, the bad, and the ugly”. It looks like a progressive three: from good, to bad, to worse. But it might be a contrasting three: bad contrasts with good, ugly contrasts with bad. Or even a dialectical three: good is the thesis, bad is the antithesis, and ugly is the synthesis: the bad which could have been good.